How can I add a blank line between list items with Ruamel?
I am appending items to a list:
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True
formatted_yaml = yaml.load(Path(my_file).open().read())

for item in my_items:
    # Just want a blank line here
    formatted_yaml.append(None)

    # Before adding this item
    formatted_yaml.append(item)

This produces:
- blah: 'sdfsdf'
  sdfsd: ''
- 
- blah: 'sdfsdf'
  sdfsd: ''
- 
- blah: 'sdfsdf'
  sdfsd: ''
- 
etc..

The output I want though is this:
- blah: 'sdfsdf'
  sdfsd: ''

- blah: 'sdfsdf'
  sdfsd: ''

- blah: 'sdfsdf'
  sdfsd: ''

etc..

Is it possible to just add an empty line like this?
I also tried adding a comment token like this:
ct = tokens.CommentToken("\n", error.CommentMark(0), None)
formatted_yaml.append(ct)

Which failed: ruamel.yaml.representer.RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: CommentToken('\n', col: 0)

What kind of brainded program creates your input, so that you have to do yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True. YAML is not allowed to have duplicate keys, you should not ignore that, you should fix it.

^ Is this setting somehow related to what I'm trying to accomplish? Also, what is a "brainded" program? This is a category of program I'm unfamiliar with. Does Ruamel not support "brainded" programs? Thanks for the help!

You include the setting in your example. so I hope it is relevant, otherwise your example is not minimal. But if it is indicative of your input being broken YAML, then the cause of that (i.e. some brainded program you are using to generate that input) should be made public so it can be properly addressed.

If you add an element None to a list and then dump that list you get an additional sequence item. If
that sequence is block style that is represent as
-

unless the null element is set to be represent in a different way in YAML ( e.g as NULL, or null, or ~).
In general you cannot add objects to a Python list and hope that changes your output sequence in YAML without
adding elements to the sequence. Adding a CommentToken will just try to add a sequence element with a representation
of that CommentToken, and you would have to tell the parser  beforehand how to represent that (hence
the RepresenterError).
As I have indicated so often here on StackOverflow, if you want to get some specific output, the FIRST STEP is to  try and round-trip
that expected output:
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """
- blah: 'sdfsdf'
  sdfsd: ''

- blah: 'sdfsdf'
  sdfsd: ''

- blah: 'sdfsdf'
  sdfsd: ''
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)

which gives:
- blah: 'sdfsdf'
  sdfsd: ''

- blah: 'sdfsdf'
  sdfsd: ''

- blah: 'sdfsdf'
  sdfsd: ''

So the empty lines are preserved. As a second step inspect data, using type() and dir()
and possible inspecting the source code (or other questions on SO):
print(data[0].ca)
print(type(data[0].ca.items['sdfsd'][2].start_mark))

showing:
Comment(comment=None,
  items={'sdfsd': [None, None, CommentToken('\n\n', line: 3, col: 0), None]})
<class 'ruamel.yaml.error.StringMark'>

Thus the mapping that is the first element of the root level sequence, gets loaded and assigned
a Comment that has \n\n as a CommentToken associated with the last key. If you would have an
end-of-line comment behind the sdfsd: '' line you would see this shows up before the first \n
and if the empty line would have a comment that would show up before the second `\n'.
Adding a newline before an additional item, can therefore be accomplished by adding a Comment to
the preceding element.
last_element = data[-1]
last_key_of_last_element = list(last_element.keys())[-1]
# c = last_element.ca
#c.items[last_key_of_last_element] = [None, None, ruamel.yaml.tokens.CommentToken('\n\n', column=1), None]
# print(last_element.ca)
last_element.ca.items[last_key_of_last_element] = data[0].ca.items['sdfsd']
data.append('and one more')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)

showing:
- blah: 'sdfsdf'
  sdfsd: ''

- blah: 'sdfsdf'
  sdfsd: ''

- blah: 'sdfsdf'
  sdfsd: ''

- and one more

It should be clear that all of this relies on ruamel.yaml internals that can change without notice. So pin
the version that you are using.
Apart from that, you should replace formatted_yaml = yaml.load(Path(my_file).open().read()) with
formatted_yaml = yaml.load(Path(my_file)). That will open the file in binary mode letting the library
deal with UTF-8  (and other unicode encodingins).

I'm sure this is not the most elegant way to do this, but this works (would love to know the "right" way to handle this).
In the loop, after appending an item, I just call yaml_set_comment_before_after_key() with the current last index number and write an empty string:
# Add a blank line at the end of the yaml file
formatted_yaml.yaml_set_comment_before_after_key(
    len(formatted_yaml) - 1, "", 0
)

It's a single call, after my append, in that loop. So at least it's pretty easy to follow what's happening.

For ruamel.yaml the right way is not to insert superfluous newlines that don't change the semantics of your YAML.
